# Access actual Features after a Feature Selection Pipeline in SciKit-Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-detection

I use a feature selection in combination with a pipeline in SciKit-Learn. As a feature selection strategy I use `SelectKBest`.

The pipeline is created and executed like this:

```
select = SelectKBest(k=5)
clf = SVC(decision_function_shape='ovo')
    parameters = dict(feature_selection__k=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 
              svc__C=[0.01, 0.1, 1],
              svc__decision_function_shape=['ovo'])
steps = [('feature_selection', select),
                 ('svc', clf)]
pipeline = sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline(steps)
cv = sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameters)
cv.fit( features_training, labels_training )
```

I know that I can get the best-parameters afterwards via `cv.best_params_`. However, this only tells me that a `k=4` is optimal. But I would like to know which features are these? How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, you can get the scores of all your features using `cv.best_estimator_.named_steps['feature_selection'].scores_`. This will give you the scores for all of your features and using them you should be able to see which were the chosen features. Similarly, you can also get the pvalues by `cv.best_estimator_.named_steps['feature_selection'].pvalues_`.

**EDIT**

A better way to get this would be to use the [`get_support`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.get_support) method of the `SelectKBest` class. This will give a boolean array of shape `[# input features]`, in which an element is *True* iff its corresponding feature is selected for retention. This will be as follows:

`cv.best_estimator_.named_steps['feature_selection'].get_support()`

Comment: nice. so if the result of `.scores_` is, for instance, `[ 891.65675063  952.43574853  739.36567492  913.33581205  753.59383098
  910.65470991  867.7711945   469.26835899]` and I see from the `best_params_` that `k=4`, then I can assume, that the 4 features with the highest values got selected? is this correct?

Comment: I think that is correct. Please check my latest edit to the answer. That is the best way to  see the chosen features.